# Linux/Ubuntu Audio Output Per Workspace/Application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, audio, media-center

I'm looking into building a media server that will output to 2 channels. I'd like to use Ubuntu however, if there's a better alternative, I'd be open to using it.

I'd have 2 audio and video cards for output and what I'm interested in knowing is if there's a way to set the audio output to a specific card per application or workspace. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Thank you for any advice you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install and run `pavucontrol`, then you can redirect streams on a per-application basis.